# Struts 2 Insert record

Tags: struts2

I want to create a addNewProduct function but having some difficuties.

```
public boolean addNewProduct(ProductBean product) {

    boolean status = false;
    Session session = null; 
    Transaction trx = null;

    try {
        session = new HibernateSession().getSession();
        trx.begin();

        status = getProductDAO(session).addNewProduct(product);
        trx.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        trx.rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return status;
}
```

the getProductDAO(session) having problem due to the session declare in getProductDAO and the setup is HttpSession. How can i solve this?

Comment: It's not at all clear what the issue is.

Comment: the problem is the session declare in addNewProduct as Session but the getProductDAO pass in parameter should be HttpSession, it cant pass in the session to the getProductDAO function. Or else i change the session declare as HttpSession in the addNewProduct function..the session.close() has error.

Comment: Then change your DAO? If you need to pass parameters then pass them. I would *not* tie your DAO to anything HTTP/Servlet related, however, instead I'd pass a parameters object, or individually if there aren't many params. Obviously what you*name* a variable is totally irrelevant; you could name them `hibernateSession` and `httpSession` if you're just having a simple name conflict. But again, don't tie your DAOs to the web layer.

Comment: Ok,,,,thank you so much....